# Альянс (в значении НАТО) с большой буквы или с маленькой?

Tags: названия, синонимы, строчная, заглавная

Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильно ли писать Альянс (как синоним НАТО) с большой буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Не имеет причины и не имеется примеров написания слова *альянс* с прописной буквы, если оно не являются частью официального названия (*участник форума «Альянс Частных Клубов»*; *СК «Альянс»*). Слово, как и ему подобные — *блог*, *союз*, *организация*, пишется со строчной (*Североатлантический альянс*; *военный альянс НАТО*).

Но в тексте, посвященном исключительно этому альянсу, прописная будет уместна, как и в случае указания: НАТО (далее — Альянс).

Comment: Официальное название: НА́ТО, Организа́ция Североатланти́ческого догово́ра, Североатлантический Алья́нс (англ. North Atlantic Treaty Organization. Пример: "В чем смысл для НАТО принимать в Альянс страны, которые отказываются размещать на своей территории натовское ядерное оружие?

Comment: Альянс — это синоним и всегда про НАТО? В тексте про (контексте) НАТО такое возможно, типа «далее — Альянс», но и только. Приватизация слова невозможна даже всеми усилиями НАТО. Со строчной С — подавлющий по численности пример.

Comment: Вот и расскажите, можно ли вообще писать Альянс с прописной буквы хотя бы в одном примере: "Для НАТО этот десятилетний отрезок получился непростым. С одной стороны, Альянс в очередной раз расширился, включив в свои ряды Черногорию и Северную Македонию".  Правильно это или нет?